# python: rename files in subfolders by subfolder name

Tags: python, os.walk, os.path

I have a folder with lots of subfolders. Eash of subfolders has different type of files. I'm trying to rename those files  by the subfolder name they are in ( the won't be duplicates as each file has it's own extension).
Data looks like this:

```
folder
        \ sub1
        \ sub1\file1.ext1
        \ sub1\file2.ext2
        .
        .
        .
        \ sub2
        \ sub2\file1.ext1
        \ sub2\file2.ext2
```

Desired output

```
  folder
    \ sub1
    \ sub1\sub1.ext1
    \ sub1\sub1.ext2
    .
    .
    .
    \ sub2
    \ sub2\sub2.ext1
    \ sub2\sub2.ext2

`
```

My bit of code which doesn't work.

```
import os

dir_name = os.getcwd() 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]#file name no ext
        os.rename(os.path.splitext(file)[0], root )
```

Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided by me below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.basename` to get the directory name of root.

```
import os

dir_name = os.getcwd() 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]#file name no ext
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        dir_name = os.path.basename(root)
        os.rename(root+"/"+file,root+"/"+dir_name+extension)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I needed